# How to properly end endless subprocess?

Tags: python, subprocess

I am using this code to read logs from mobile device:

```
with subprocess.Popen(read_device_logs_cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=1,
                              universal_newlines=True, errors="replace") as p:

    for line in p.stdout:
        save(line)
```

So `p` will be running endlessly. 
Edit: and important info, this subprocess is running in Thread so I can manipulate loop inside of subprocess from other part of code.

How can I correctly stop `p` programatically?

In terminal I'd just have to do `CTRL + C`.

Will `p.kill()` or `p.terminate()` do the job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`p.kill()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.kill) to kill a subprocess.